# What is the one glaring omission Vala talks about?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In episode "200" of *SG-1*, Vala says about Sci-Fi programs on TV:

> ... and apart from one glaring omission, it doesn't seem to be that bad.

What is that glaring omission?

Comment: "Wormhole eXtreme", I'd guess. They _are_ discussing a bad script from that series...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script for "200":

> VALA
>
> Um, I've been looking at this, and there doesn't seem to be any mention of a sexy female alien… anywhere! I'm not even in this!
>
> [Carter shoots Vala a disbelieving look. Daniel casts a side long glance at Vala and sighs.]
>
> CARTER
>
> You know, the really unbelievable part is that anyone would consider spending millions of dollars on this. I mean, seriously, all these writers, and they couldn't come up with anything better?
>
> VALA
>
> I don't know, I've been watching a lot of television lately, and apart from one glaring omission, it doesn't seem to be that bad.

I think it's pretty obvious that she is talking about the movie script, and only referring to the other sci-fi as a reference to compare the script again. So, the glaring omission is the "sexy female alien" - or, rather, Vala herself.

To parse the script: Carter says the script is bad - Vala says the script isn't that bad compared to what else she's seen on TV, except for...

Comment: Except that she's not referencing the script, she's referencing what she's been watching on television.

Comment: Yes, she's referencing the shows on TV (I even say she is in my answer) - to say that the script isn't bad compared to them, except for...

Answer (score 15):

I always assumed, considering she is reading the "Wormhole eXtreme" script, she was talking about herself, or rather her expy; being the latest addition to the team, I assumed Martin hadn't included her yet.

Comment: Yeah I thought this was obvious too tbh.

Answer (score 6):

It's not explicitly stated, but it's fairly obvious she's referring to *Stargate: SG-1* itself. The vast majority of that episode is one great big in-joke. This is similar to the MacGyver reference in the pilot.

Comment: Vala isn't aware of the existence of a series named "Stargate: SG-1". It's not part of her universe. When they become self-referential they use the vehicle and talk about "Wormhole eXtreme" - which is supposed to be Stargate - no doubt - but that's not what Vala is talking about.

Comment: Of course she isn't aware of any such show. But looking for canonicity or an in-universe explanation on this particular episode does't really make sense. It is, as I said in my answer, essentially one big in-joke.

Comment: Of course it's meant to be a joke, and of course the joke is on Stargate. And Claudia Black talks about Stargate, but not Vala and that was the op-question: Strictly in-universe. But sure: The scriptwriters _meant_ "Stargate" when they let Vala _talk_ about "Wormhole eXtreme".

Comment: I thought it might be Farscape being off the air, but I couldn't find any more details to the in-joke.